# Borders and sorting formula called values

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a number of importrange formula on a hidden store sheet. Various different sheets 'lookup' this data to display in a table. I have set up a simple script to draw borders when a new row of data is entered. This works fine.

I added a new line to get the data to sort so the newest entry appears first. I would just add a `sort` equation onto the lookup but one element on the sheet is typed by the user and this would be in the wrong place whilst the others moved. For this reason, and since the script is already triggered, I added the extra line. I get the error `Cell reference out of range (line 15, file "macros")` and I do not understand why.

Here is my code

```
function onEdit(){

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange(6, 2, 35);
  var values = range.getValues().map(function(d){ return d[0] });
Logger.log(values);

  var index = values.indexOf("");
  Logger.log(index);


      var border = sheet.getRange(5, 2, index+1, 5);
      border.setBorder(true, true, true, true, true, true);

  range.sort({column : 1, ascending: true});

  }
```

EDIT

I have added a link to a sample sheet. The imported data is on sheet 16, I have included an example of how the data is sorted for Maths only. When you look at the maths sheet the date is returned to the relevant columns. There is a comment added by the viewer. I am trying to get the data sorted with an on open script so the third row of entered data appears first and any further data entries will be correctly sorted too. 
[example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1k91IiozzwGXtwEm3TMpdWJ7e9BPiRFo7t39RYwyA9Wg/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Are you trying to sort the first column selected from the range?

Comment: yes, the first column is a date entry, although I haven't specifically formatted the cells to date (not yet anyway, i completely forgot about it)

Comment: sorry, sort the whole range based on the first column

Comment: That must be the problem the sort function is only for the column not the range?

Comment: @ck88 in general "sorting formulas" doesn't really make sense. You sort the values that go into the formulas. If you sort via the sheet UI, does it do what you want?

Comment: If I understand the question correctly no. The importrange is a long string and this is dividing into 4 sections. Each of those sections is displayed in 4 columns on a different sheet. The viewer can add a comment into the 5th column. The data entry is done periodically and I wanted to apply a sort so that the newest entry appears first. If I add sort into the formula it does not organise the comments in the 5th column.

Answer (score 0):

In here

```
var range = sheet.getRange(6, 2, 35);
```

you are getting the cells from row 6, column B to row 35, column B. And here

```
range.sort({column : 1, ascending: true});
```

You are trying to sort column A in ascending in the range above. You should set `column` to be the same as the `column` argument in your `range`, like this

```
range.sort({column : 2, ascending: true});
```

## Edit

If you want to sort rows of data by the first column, you will have to supply more sort objects as sort parameters in a single array

```
var range               = sheet.getRange( "B6:F36" );
var firstColumnPosition = range.getColumn();
var lastColumnPosition  = range.getLastColumn();
var sortParameters      = [];

for ( var i = firstColumnPosition; i <= lastColumnPosition; i++ ) {
    sortParameters.push( { column:i, ascending:true } );
}

range.sort( sortParameters );
```

Comment: ok, I thought it called the columns like in a query col1, 2 etc. When I make that change I get the error `The coordinates of the range are outside the dimensions of the sheet`

Comment: So i realised that I want to sort a range not just a single column. I edited my code to be `var selection = sheet.getRange("B6:F36")
  selection.sort({column : 2, ascending: true});` This however does not correctly sort the available data

Comment: @ck88 Updated my answer to sort by first column

Comment: Thank you for the update. I tried the code but it does not sort the columns. The data values are via formula, so maybe it does not read these correctly. I tried adding  `.getvalues()` but this resulted in an error.

Comment: So I can get some sorting but it sorts the actual formula so they move rather than just the values. Is it possible to take the array of values and sort this without moving the formula? So if new data is added the formula calls it up and then the script picks off all available values then sorts on an open trigger. This is proving to be a lot more complicated then first envisaged.

Comment: In that case, you will need to [get the values](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues), [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) it and [put it back](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)

Comment: Right, thanks for you help I will give that a go. My only question here is that once the array is sorted and I look to return the data values will it replace the original formula? If an extra row is then added later it will not appear

Comment: If you want to retain the formula you might be interested in [`getFormulas`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getformulas) and [`setFormulas`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setformulasformulas).